# Inconsistent results converting unsigned [char, short, int, long] to double

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  unsigned char c = 10;
  unsigned short d = 10;
  unsigned int e = 10;
  unsigned long f = 10;
  double g = -c;
  double h = -d;
  double i = -e;
  double j = -f;
  printf("%d %lf\n", c, g);
  printf("%u %lf\n", d, h);
  printf("%u %lf\n", e, i);
  printf("%lu %lf\n", f, j);
}
```

gives as output

```
10 -10.000000
10 -10.000000
10 4294967286.000000
10 18446744073709551616.000000
```

Why are the results inconsistent, yielding -10 for some types and huge values for others?

Comment: Integral promotion convert the first two to larger, signed types (`int`); for the second two: just unary minus applied to unsigned types.

Comment: Why is this considered a bad question?

Comment: I am bewildered by the downvotes. A little more explanation about why the observed results are surprising would be helpful, but it's a valid question about a fairly subtle aspect of C expression evaluation. Will someone please comment and explain?

Comment: @DyP I also think that this question is perfectly fine. It is well drafted, shows example code and describes a problem that is not that obvious (unary operator integral promotion).

Comment: This is one of the reasons that you shouldn't use unsigned types in C++ unless you want modulo arithmetic. Wanting to prohibit negative values isn't sufficient, and I've heard C++ committee members express regret that they specified parts of the standard library to use unsigned types on that basis.

Comment: I think the questions title should be improved to be more meaningful.  Easier for future reverences.  Something like "Why apparently _inconsistent_ unsigned [char, short, int, long] to double _conversion_?"

Comment: @chux: Updated. bruno, please check my edit and make sure I haven't messed anything up.

Comment: Everything seems fine, Keith. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The operand of a unary `-` operator is *promoted*; types narrower than `int` are promoted to `int` or to `unsigned int`.

Since (signed) `int` can hold all the values that can be represented by an `unsigned char`, the value `(unsigned char)10` is promoted to the *signed* `int` value `10`. Negating that gives you the (signed) `int` value `-10`, which is then converted to `double`.

An `unsigned int` is not "promoted" to `int`, because `int` can't hold all the values. So the expression `-e` applies the `unsigned int` negation operator, which obviously cannot yield a negative value. The result is `UINT_MAX + 1 - 10`, which on your system is `4294967286`. Converting to `double` yields the value you see.

Likewise, `unsigned long` is not promoted, so `-f` yields `ULONG_MAX + 1 - 10`, which when converted to `double` yields `18446744073709551606` (2<sup>64</sup>-10) (apparently your system has 64-bit `long` and `unsigned long`). Converting that value to `double` loses some precision, yielding the value you see.

Aside from the promotion rules, it's important to remember that the type of a C expression is (almost always) not affected by the context in which it appears. `-f` yields a result of the same value and type regardless of what it's assigned to.

Comment: Shouldn't the `unsigned long` case be converted to `ULONG_MAX + 1 - 10` (not `UINT_MAX`)? I'm sure it's just a typo...

Comment: Like the part about `18446744073709551606` converts to `18446744073709551616.000000`.